# How do I find Hamiltonian with a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I had one physics class before so I still remember something about Hamiltonian as we express from kinetic and potential energy. Now I'm working on PDEs and I'm supposed to express equations as Hamiltonian system, for example, Korteweg-de Vries equation $\dot u=-u'''+uu'$, I've no idea about how to find energies, Lagrangian, etc. However all examples I had uses energies. Please help.

Comment: Do you know what it means to put a PDE into Hamiltonian form? Have you seen the analogous situation for ODEs?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Sorry no, I used to see things like $H=T+U$. Is $\dot{u}=J\nabla H$ the key to solutions?

Comment: Sort of. You can put an ODE in Hamiltonian form as $\dot{u}=J\nabla H$, but this doesn't make sense for PDEs. There is a generalisation to PDEs which is a bit more complicated: it looks like $u_{t}=J\delta H[u]$.